# Create a Load Balancer with the pre-created static IP address on Google Cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, load-balancing

I need my services to be available with the specific IP address, which I created on GCP: [external IPs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oGPgG.png)

The problem is that when I configure the frontend of my new Load Balancer I can only choose an Ephemeral IP or randomly generate a new one, which is not appropriate. Pre-created addresses are not available: [configuring frontend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKRg6.png)

How can I bind my IP address with the Load Balancer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use a reserved static IP address for a Google HTTP(S) Load Balancer, the IP address must be created with `Type` as `Global`. Your IP addresses are `Regional`.

Comment: Thank you! Do you know if I can change the type of an existing IP to Global?

Comment: You cannot change the type from Regional to Global. You can create a new address. Global addresses use Anycast, which is different than normal IP addresses.